# How to see if a list item in a dictionary is equal to another item but with a different key in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I have a python dict of the form of `final = collections.defaultdict(Tuple)` where the key is `user` and the tuple values are `(sat,color)`.

Now the question I have is how can I get the list of keys(user) where their respective `(sat,color)` values are the same/equal?

Comment: provide your necessary code or set an example  while asking question

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension for that:

```
{k: v for k, v in final.items() if v[0]==v[1]}
```